# Why does standing for too long make knees sore?

Tags: knees

I don't seem to get sore knees unless i stand still for extended periods of time.

My knees are fine when I skateboard or do exercise though so it made me curious.

EDIT: I skateboard for more than 4 hours and am fine afterwords. I only get the pain when I stand still in one spot. For example, if I stand at the computer for 4 hours in the same position then my knees will be sore.

Comment: What's an extended period of time? Because I can't imagine you skateboard for 4 hours non-stop, but if you have to work standing that's pretty likely to happen. Also care to explain how this relates to actual exercise? Because simply standing still has nothing to do with exercising. [See this Meta discussion for more information.](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/137/reviewing-the-site-scope)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if you move around while you're standing, shift your weight a lot, and bend your knees occasionally it will help. In other words, look like you have to go to the restroom all the time.

Comment: I skateboard for more than 4 hours and am fine afterwords. I only get the pain when I stand still in one spot. For example, if I stand at the computer for 4 hours in the same position then my knees will be sore.

Comment: I have the same problem and my calves get tight and balloon up like i have been workin out my calves for hours

Answer (score 5):

It could be that you're standing with bad posture. That is, if you're standing for long periods of time, you may become tired and let your weight sag inward on your knees. When you're exercising, you're obviously moving around so the weight isn't constantly on your knees. Even if you do certain exercises that put pressure on them (like running), you're still shifting your weight while you move.

If you are standing with bad posture, and you are constantly supporting your weight with your knees rather than with your leg muscles, you might be damaging the cartilage. Check out [this article](http://www.drbookspan.com/KneePainArticle.html) for details on how to correct that problem.

Answer (score 1):

patellofemoral syndrome is probably what you have! I had the same problem; not being able to sit/stand/kneel for long periods of time (5-10 minsutes tops) without my joints in my knees hurting.

Comment: Can you add some more content to define what that is, what will help it, and how to tell if you have it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patellofemoral_pain_syndrome

Comment: @RobinAshe - I'm hoping for some improvement on the answer here, not JUST a link leading our users elsewhere for the information they're looking for. References are definitely a plus, but we should have a summary here as well.